# pick first day from many panda dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes that contain

```
Name - category - type
---------------------------
Date - index - datetime64
X -  variable - str
Y -  variable - str
```

All dataframes are sorted by its index(`Date`). So first entry is the earliest day of the each dataframe.

```
df1
Date          X      Y      
2017-09-11  foo     bar
2017-09-12   foo    bar

df2
Date          X      Y      
2017-01-13  foo     bar
2017-02-12   foo    bar

df3
Date          X      Y      
2017-08-21  foo     bar
2017-10-12   foo    bar
```

I want to get `first_day` of each frame, for example,

```
first_day_df1 = "2017-09-11"
first_day_df2 = "2017-01-13"
first_day_df3 = "2017-10-12"
```

I have tried `iloc`,`loc` and just indexing but no luck.
`df.iloc[0]` returns all variables in this entry and `df.iloc[0].index` returns name of variables.
 `df.loc[0]` and `df[0]` of course throws errors. Any help appreciated!

*
pandas: 0.22.0
python: 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need select first value of index by `[0]`, because sorted `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df1.index[0]
```

If not sorted:

```
df1.index.min()
```

If all `DataFrames` are in list:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
L = [x.index[0] for x in dfs]
```

Comment: If I do df1.index[0], it returns `0` not data, why ? @jezrael , my `df1.dtypes= Date    object
X       object
Y       object
dtype: object\`

Comment: @pyd - It depends if datetimeindex or not, but if check `4.line` of OP question `Date - index - datetime64` there is not default index, but datetimeindex.

Answer (score 0):

Just use slicing + max():

```
first_day_df1 = df1["Date"].min()
```

If "Date" is the index, then:

```
first_day_df1 = df1.index.min()
```

Comment: If your Date column is index, then use df.index.max()

Comment: It is actually df.index.min(), since I am looking for the first day

Comment: @jaykodeveloper My bad, I was answering question on mobile and didn't pay 100% attention into the detail. However, I guess you get the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
first_day1 = df1.head(1)
```

This will only work if the daraframe is sorted.